# Area based feature extraction after labeling algorithm

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to apply a labeling algorithm to label crops and weeds in an image. After that, I have to apply some area based feature extraction. I wrote the code for labeling algorithm but whenever I run that code it shows so many labels (like 1500 to 1600). I don't undestand how to apply area based feature extraction on this labeling algorithm.

Here is the code of the labelling algorithm:

```
A=imread('Capture.PNG');
figure,imshow(A);
title('Original image');
B=im2bw(A);
figure,imshow(B);
label=bwlabel(B);
max(max(label))
im1= (label==1);
figure,imshow(im1);

figure,imshow(label==6);

for j=1:max(max(label))
[row, col] = find(label==j);
len=max(row)-min(row)+2;
breadth=max(col)-min(col)+2;
target=uint8(zeros([len breadth] ));
sy=min(col)-1;
sx=min(row)-1;

for i=1:size(row,1)
x=row(i,1)-sx;
y=col(i,1)-sy;
target(x,y)=A(row(i,1),col(i,1));
end
mytitle=strcat('Object Number:',num2str(j));
figure,imshow(target);title(mytitle);
a=size(target);
ax=a(1);
ay=a(2);
pos=[1,1,ay,ax];
rectangle('Position',pos,'EdgeColor','r')
end
```

Input image:

[image]

Output image:

[image]

The output image must contain detected regions of crop (after area based feature extraction)